# Trying to animate a character walking

Tags: animation

So I have this rig of a Minecraft character walking and im trying to rotate the chest of her back and forth, but the chest stops rotating halfway through and seems to snap weirdly. Is there any way I can fix this, does it have something to do with my keyframes? [image]

The chest rotations are at keyframes 1, 13, and 25, the chest seems to snap to it's original position midway and it looks bad.

Comment: hello, maybe share your file so that we understand more easily (at least the armature if it's enough)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi moonboots, I shared the file at the link you sent.